# Relation one to zero or one

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, relationship

[edit: EntityFramework version is 6.0.0.0 runtime v4.0.030319 (should be EF6)]

I'm stuck on the implementation on multiple relations one to zero or one. I read many documents and StackOverflow posts, but nothing seems work well.

I have two entities, Dogs and Cats, and a table that is in relation with those two, Pets

```
[Table("Dogs")]
public class Dog
{
   [Key, ForeignKey("Pet")]
   public int DogID { get; set; }

   public Pet Pet { get; set; }
}

[Table("Cats")]
public class Cat
{
   [Key, ForeignKey("Pet")]
   public int CatID { get; set; }

   public Pet Pet { get; set; }
}

[Table("Pets")]
public class Pet
{
   [Key]
   public int PetID { get; set; }

   public int? DogID { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("DogID")]
   public Dog Dog { get; set; }

   public int? CatID { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("CatID")]
   public Cat Cat { get; set; }
}
```

I also override DbContext as follow:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Pet>()
               .HasOptional(pet => pet.Dog)
               .WithRequired(dog => dog.Pet)
               .Map(pet => pet.MapKey("DogID"));

   modelBuilder.Entity<Pet>()
               .HasOptional(pet => pet.Cat)
               .WithRequired(cat => cat.Pet)
               .Map(pet => pet.MapKey("CatID"));
```

In my mind, if I add a dog, for example using this pattern:

```
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
   Dog d = db.Dogs.Create();
   Pet p = db.Pets.Create();
   d.Pet = p;
   p.Dog = d;
   db.Pets.Add(p);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I should get for example the follow result:

```
+-----------------------+
| DOGS TABLE            |
+-------+---------------+
| DogID |
+-------+
|   7   |
+-------+

+-----------------------+
| PETS TABLE            |
+-------+-------+-------+
| PetID | DogID | CatID |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   2   |   7   | NULL  |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

and Dog's "Pet.PetID" property should be 2 after the insert.

But my result is something like that:

```
+-----------------------+
| DOGS TABLE            |
+-------+---------------+
| DogID |
+-------+
|   7   |
+-------+

+-----------------------+
| PETS TABLE            |
+-------+-------+-------+
| PetID | DogID | CatID |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   7   | NULL  | NULL  |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I tried many solutions, but i didn't get the correct solution. What I did wrong?

Comment: Please always choose a tag indicating the exact EF version you're using. EF has a very unsteady recent history. In this case it's clear from the syntax that it's EF6 (classic) but not everyone will notice that.

Comment: That said, when I try your code I get al kinds of errors. I understand you tried to show a [mre], which is great, but you better make it work :).

Comment: Thank you @GertArnold, i correct something and now can be compiled and tested in the solution (but still doesn't work as I wish)

Comment: "The navigation property 'Pet' declared on type 'Cat' has been configured with conflicting foreign keys." Anyway. EF6 only supports shared key relationships in 1:1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#configuring-a-required-to-optional-relationship-one-tozero-or-one

Comment: Thank you one more time, @GertArnold, but how did you get the message "The navigation property 'Pet' declared on type 'Cat' has been configured with conflicting foreign keys."?

Comment: Trying to create a database using your code.